# RVM: How to set up two separate environments for someone that is afraid of the Terminal?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

So, I have two apps. And of course, all the gems conflict with each other, so I really just need two separate environments. I know RVM is capable of this, but I find it unintuitive, as it seems really complex.

So, is there like a GUI frontend for RVM? or a super detailed step-by-step guide for setting up two different app environments with different versions of rubygems?

Thanks =\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite simple to do it in terminal, for example:

Use ruby 1.9.2:

```
rvm 1.9.2
```

Create as many gemsets as you like, named whatever you like:

```
rvm gemset create lovelygemset
rvm gemset create anothergemset
```

Use the gemset you want:

```
rvm use lovelygemset
```

Comment: Can I get away with ruby 1.8.7?

Comment: You can use any version of ruby with rvm, that's the point of it :-)

Comment: when I try using the gem set, it says ERROR: Unrecognized command line argument

Answer (score 1):

Agree that setting up RVM is not exactly straight forward.

Fortunately, you don't necessarily need RVM unless your different apps require different versions of the Ruby interpreter. If it's just a matter of managing gems, then [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) makes it a breeze.

http://gembundler.com/

You just specify the list of gems each application requires in a Gemfile, then run `bundle install` to install them all. Bundler will manage dependancies and keep different gem sets separate for each app.